# DTD: elements #PCDATA with default value, can be?

Tags: dtd

I have an element that can be "16:9" or "4:3", is it possible to write something like this:

`<!ELEMENT element_name (16:9|4:3)>` ?

Eclipse gives me error with every way I've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DTDs can't control the text content of elements. You need XML Schema for this. The best you can do for text content is:

```
<!ELEMENT element_name (#PCDATA) >
```

This declaration

```
<!ELEMENT element_name (a|b) >
```

means that `<element_name>` can contain either `<a>...</a>` or `<b>...</b>`.

Your declaration:

```
<!ELEMENT element_name (16:9|4:3)>
```

attempts to declare that the element `<element_name>` can contain either an element named `<16:9>` or `<4:3>`. That is not valid because XML elements *cannot have names that begin with numbers*. The document will not be well-formed and as such could not be validated by a DTD.

*Source*: From the [XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-suggested-names):

> The first character of any name should have a Unicode property of ID_Start, or else be '_' #x5F.

**ID_Start** represents a character allowed as the first character of an identifier, which, according to the definition in "[Unicode Default Identifier Syntax](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Default_Identifier_Syntax)" excludes numbers.